# Display .pptx file with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have a file in the device's internal storage. Tried different ways but did not find any solution. Now I want to display it using WebView but confuse about how to show the Powerpoint file stored in internal storage. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No need to use web view. Please refer this - https://pub.dev/packages/open_file

Comment: but the open file called the suggested apps to open i want to open it within the app